# Seeing if a string contains a substring in C

Tags: c, string, pointers

I have the task of finding out if one of the many strings in my array contains an `@` character.

Example -

```
I am @HOME or @SCHOOL
```

If the string does contain the `@` i want to print out the string.

`arr` is declared as follows

```
char* arr[10][100];
```

I thought of using this

```
   if(strstr(arr[j], "@") != NULL);
   {
      printf("hey\n");
   }
```

but it prints out every single string whether or not they have the @.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove semicolon after the `if` condition. Like

```
if(strstr(outputArr[j], "@") != NULL)
```

Because

```
 if(strstr(outputArr[j], "@") != NULL);
```

is equivalent to

```
if(strstr(outputArr[j], "@") != NULL)
{

}
```

C99-6.8.3 paragraph 3:

> A null statement (consisting of just a semicolon) performs no operations.